# Linking two analytical charts in PPS

Tags: performancepoint, dashboard-designer

Is it possible to link two analytical charts on a dashboard?  For example I want to be able to click on a bar in one analytical chart and have it show another analytcal bar chart depending on which bar I clicked on.

The technology that I am using here is Sharepoint Performance Point services. SSAS cube is input to this dashboard.

Comment: You should provide more details what technology you are talking about, which charts or dashboard you are talking about. Otherwise people won't understand your question and you won't get answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link reports, but you can link scorecards to reports.

Connect a PerformancePoint scorecard item to an analytic chart or grid
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh133421.aspx